# Python lossy conversion from float to int

Tags: python, floating-point, int

I am trying to figure out a way to write 21*(10^21) in Python. I've tried two approaches. The first one is simply by doing the following:

```
>>> print(21*(10**21))
21000000000000000000000
```

This works just fine. However, the problem I'm trying to solve requires me to get to this number by iteration, i.e, by building up from 1*(10^1) all the way to 21*(10^21). So I tried the following:

```
>>> temp = 20*(10**20)
>>> print(21*temp*10/20)
2.1e+22
```

Now, I want the entire number to show up, and not in the 'e' form, so I converted it to `int`. But this prints the wrong answer:

```
>>> print(int(21*temp*10/20))
20999999999999997902848
```

I know that integers don't have a limit in Python 3 (which is what I'm using) so this baffles me. I thought this may be because the `/20` part causes conversion to `float`, but the number `21*(10^21)` falls within the limits of `float`, so converting back to `int` shouldn't be a problem.

I've tried searching for this error online with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Even for values within its range, floats still have limited precision.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: If I recall correctly, `/` in Python 3 produces a floating-point result, but `//` produces an integer result. Try `21*temp*10//20`.

Comment: @FlyingTeller: This is not a duplicate of that question, as this question involves largely Python type semantics. Please do not promiscuously mark questions as a duplicate of that one.